# flask-admin queryset analog from django-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm using SQLAlchemy ModelView

Well, I'm trying to manage per-item permissions in my admin. So, users can change only that model instances, they created.

I can add column "author" with relation to "User" table.

After that, in django-admin typically we use

```
def queryset:
    qs = super(...
    qs = qs.filter(author = request.user)
    return qs
```

So, how to do this in flask-admin. Mb, it's definitely another way, and maybe there is "queryset" analog?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do that, but some of the docs for flask admin can be hard to come by, and in this case, as in many others, your best bet is to read the source code, you could use:
[BaseModelAdmin.get_list](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1446) to customize the list result set, or [BaseModelAdmin.get_one](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1471) to customize how a single object is loaded, or [flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.get_query](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L782), so the closest to what your asking for would be:

```
 from flask import current_user
 from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

 class SomeView(ModelView):
     def get_query(self,*args,**kwargs):
         qs = super(SomeView,self).get_query(*args,**kwargs)
         qs = qs.filter_by(author=current_user)
         return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to flask-admin I think.

You can override the `.query` of your `Flask-SQLAlchemy` model in exact the same way of `Django`.